# How to set `umask` for the entire gnome session?

Tags: gnome3, umask

Using Gnome 3.18. I share files between other family members, but the default umask on my distro (archlinux) is `0022`. So every file/directory created is not writable for our common group.

I tried to put `umask 0002` in `/etc/profile` but the gnome session is still using `0022`. It's working for a login bash shell, though.

I also tried to add this line in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`:

`session   required  pam_umask.so umask=0002`

It has the same effect as the one in `/etc/profile`.
I tried

If I change the umask manually in a gnome-terminal shell, then I launch an application from it, say gedit, then the files created by it have the wanted permissions. If I launch gedit from the gnome menus, it doesn't. So my matter is really to set the umask for the gnome session, and I can't find where to do it.

EDIT (to answer Gilles' comment):
I'm using gdm 3.18 as the DM.
I also tried to add the pam_umask line into `/etc/pam.d/gdm-launch-environment`. All other `gdm-*` files contains includes of `session` from the `system-auth` file, so they should not need more. It doesn't change anything.

`/etc/login.defs` contains `UMASK 077` but also `USERGROUPS_ENAB yes` which should set the `umask` to either `0077` or `0007` for users whose primary group is the username.

The only file that contains `022` for umask in `/etc` is `/etc/profile` but that was my first try.

As for `/etc/Xsession.d`, I don't have this directory. Besides, as wayland is now the default display server, I'm not sure the umask should be set as part of X initialisation, even if I'm still using it myself.

Comment: What display manager do you use? (That's the program where you enter your username and password.) Gdm, lightdm, slim, xdm, kdm, …? Depending on how Arch and your DM are set up, try adding a file in `/etc/Xsession.d`, or a different file in `/etc/pam.d` (I'm assuming you want to set this system-wide). Or maybe `/etc/login.defs`.

Comment: The two answers are valid for `tty` or `ssh` logins, and they are basically the same one, really (using `pam_umask`). They don't work with my gnome session. So I can't give the bounty to anyone. I don't know if this is specific to gnome on Xorg on archlinux. I'll test with other distributions when I have some time.

Comment: There is a similar thread on the archlinux forum treating the issue: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=207753 Seems like a bug in gdm...

Comment: I ended up using ACLs, which is a much better way of controlling permissions. No need to change the default safer permissions mask.

Answer (score 7):

Some Gnome applications are launched by `systemd --user`, in which case umask is set by systemd to `0022` regardless of the configured value for *pam_umask*. I am not aware of any workarounds, but I opened *[an issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6077)* on systemd github issue tracker. This issue is also reported on [*Gnome bugzilla*](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=780622).

Umask set using `pam_umask` is working as expected for applications which are not launched by `systemd --user`.

One workaround is suggested on [Ubuntu bugzilla](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1685754/comments/21) to place systemd service overrides to all affected applications.

**Update:** pam_umask should work as expected for systemd version 246 and newer. Newer distribution releases should ship with a version where the bug is fixed.

---

***To investigate this yourself***

You can list the processes running on your system in a tree format (parent/child processes) using:

```
pstree -Tapu
```

Find ***PIDs*** for: *(1)* your session's instance of *systemd --user*; *(2)* *an application launched by it*, such as gedit, which will show as child process to *systemd --user*; and *(3)* a process in your session *not launched by systemd --user*.

Compare *umasks* reported in *procfs*:

```
grep Umask /proc/<pid>/status
```

*systemd --user* itself *(1)* and processes *not* launched by it *(3)* should have the correct *umask* which was set by *pam_umask*. Processes launched by *systemd --user* *(2)* will have umask of `0022`.

Comment: See also Debian bug [#991857](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=991857).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that mentioned by Sebasth. I tried many things, but then I found a workaround which consists in overwriting the (per-user) UMask of dbus:

```
$ systemctl --user edit dbus
```

In the file that gets opened, just write:

```
[Service]
UMask=002 # This is the umask I want to use
```

The file gets saved in .config/systemd/user/dbus.service.d/override.conf
and overrides the dbus default umask, which I presume is inherited from systemd --user, since dbus is launched by it. Just logout and login again and gnome applications should use the specified umask. Just a workaround, but it works for me.

Comment: Is it still a working solution? For CentOS 8 and Gnome 3?

Comment: No apparent effect under Debian Bullseye.

Answer (score 2):

To set default umask system-wide you will have to enable it in first place, which pretty well explained here:

```
http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pam_umask&sektion=8
```

The above link is for debian and ubuntu but the same for all other linux systems.

To enable it umask (which maybe already in place) you need to add a line to `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session optional pam_umask.so
```

Once enabled you can then set it up in:

```
/etc/login.defs
```

I see you already found this file so all you need to do is to set:

```
# The permission mask is initialized to this value. If not specified,
# the permission mask will be initialized to 022.
UMASK           077
```

And set it UMASK to 0002 or whatever you'd like to.

This will set default value system-wide, which means all users will have pick up the umask from there unless they don't specifically set otherwise in their *.profile*  or *.bashrc*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll have to try that. I'm not that optimistic because I already tried this PAM module with an inline parameter "umask=0002" and it didn't work (for Gnome, it did work for other login shells, though). I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: you tried pam module for system-auth not common-auth:-)

Comment: It's just a matter of distribution choice of file names. I know debian uses `common-*` for common settings. Arch, as RedHat, uses a `system-auth` file for this. Anyway, I tried your suggestion of adding `session optional pam_umask.so` and and `UMASK 002` into `/etc/login.defs` As I expected, and as with `pam_umask.so umask=0002`, it worked for a tty `login` session (or through SSH) but Gnome set a `0022` umask as always. Gnome must use an internal umask setting, or archlinux is using one… I'll try another distribution to see if the issue arises too.

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest way, even the distribution I am using has already prepared `common-session` accordingly including a nice comment.

Answer (score 2):

Instead changing the `umask` you could use the `usergroups` option for `pam_umask`, with this user and group has the same permissions, as the classical unix way to share folders.

```
# /etc/pam.d/login or
# /etc/pam.d/common-session or system-auth
session optional pam_umask.so usergroups
```

Comment: If the user is not root and the **username is the same as primary group name**, the umask group bits are set to be the same as owner bits (examples: 022 -> 002, 077 -> 007).

Comment: I use the primary group as the sharing group. With user groups, files will be created with this user group by default, and not editable by other users.

Comment: I see a way, though: I can use user groups, and a common secondary group, and then, on the shared tree, add a "set group" bit to force this common group on all created files and folders. Anyway, I'll try on my PC later. I'm not sure gnome will care about that anyway, because it always take 0022 as a umask, no matter what is working for tty sessions.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: To get systemd to set the gnome session's umask, I created a umask.conf file under /etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service.d/ with the following lines:

```
[Service]
UMask=0002
```

After rebooting the machine, this now  allows all processes under `user.slice` to conform to the umask you would like. Logging out was not sufficient for the changes to take place so i would advise to reboot your machine before performing the [tests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379329/262925) on process umasks.

￼
**Additional Info:**

- OS: CentOS7.4
- DE: Gnome3

Comment: If it's working, then a file like `/etc/systemd/system/gdm.service.d/umask.conf` containing only `[Service]\nUMask=0002` should be enough.

Comment: And indeed it does! just tested it there. my /etc/systemd/system/ folder contains a symlink to gdm.service so i created a display-manager.service.d/umask.conf and added the line, this worked perfect, going to update the answer to include it.Thank you @ChristopheDrevet-Droguet

Comment: No apparent effect under debian Bullseye

Answer (score 0):

For the login session: add `umask 0002` to your `$HOME/.profile` (or `/etc/profile`).

For the Gnome session: add `umask 0002` to your `$HOME/.gnomerc`

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that the `pam_umask` manpages provide some pretty good info to help you figure out where your umask is coming from. Specifically:

> pam_umask is a PAM module to set the file mode creation mask of the current environment. The umask affects the default permissions assigned to newly created files.
>
> The PAM module tries to get the umask value from the following places in the following order:
>
> ```
> ·   umask= argument
> ·   umask= entry of the users GECOS field
> ·   pri= entry of the users GECOS field
> ·   ulimit= entry of the users GECOS field
> ·   UMASK= entry from /etc/default/login
> ·   UMASK entry from /etc/login.defs
> ```

As somebody has stated, you should set this up in the `common-session` file in the directory `/etc/pam.d`.

Do note that logins which do not use pam (such as those that use `getty` or `login` will have their umask set via `login.defs`.

Answer (score 0):

On a install of Fedora 29 with Gnome I found that, programs launched from the Gnome launcher left files other readable, 0022.  Pam apparently defers to /etc/login.defs as noted above. However, editing the mask there, 0077, did not change Gnome's behavior.  I also had to edit /etc/profile, and to /etc/bashrc - both of which were setting it back to 0022.

It would be nice if Fedora had one place for this, but the entries in /etc/profile and /etc/bashrc set the mask differently for users with IDs above or below 200, so it seems that one mask does not fit all.

Though this is a fix for now, the problem isn't completely solved, as the gnome user still has no way of setting his or her own umask as it is applied to applications that run from the gnome launcher.  Seems Gnome should have a config option for that umask.  (Maybe it does, but I didn't find it.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the workaround at least on Fedora 31:

```
sudo vi /etc/profile.d/umask.sh
umask <your_umask>

sudo vi /etc/login.defs
UMASK <your_umask>

sudo vi /usr/local/bin/systemd-user
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user

sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/systemd-user

sudo vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service
ExecStart=-/usr/local/bin/systemd-user
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 & GNOME 3.36.8

To have `systemd --user` apps set to a specific `umask`

in `/etc/login.defs` change `UMASK` and `USERGROUPS_ENAB` according to your needs.

For example:

`UMASK 0027` with `USERGROUPS_ENAB yes` - leads to `systemd --user` apps using `umask 0007`

`UMASK 0027` with `USERGROUPS_ENAB  no` - leads to `systemd --user` apps using `umask 0027`

NOTE: After every `/etc/login.defs` change a reboot is required

NOTE: If you set `USERGROUPS_ENAB no` use `useradd -U` when you create new users, if you want to create a group with the same name as the user, and add the user to this group, otherwise without `-U` a `useradd` will set the primary group of the new user to the value specified by the GROUP variable in /etc/default/useradd, or 100 by default: `gid=100(users) groups=100(users)`.