# Share folder/files between multiple users on ext4 disk

Tags: permissions, filesystems, ext4

Here's the situation -

1. I have a 1TB drive mounted at `/data`.
2. There are multiple local users on the desktop. All of them are in the `localusers` group
3. I have a virtualbox VM with a 50 GB VDI dsik stored at `/data/common/vms`

I would like the virtualbox VM to be available to all members of the `localusers` group.

What I've done so far:

1. As the primary user, create the VM
2. Moved the vbox machine folder to `/data/common/vbox` [so if the machine is Win10Pro, then I have the folder at `/data/common/vbox/Win10Pro`]
3. Group Perms - group of the folder to `localusers` and `chmod -R g+rw /data/common/vbox /data/common/vms`
4. Copied over `~/.Virtualbox/Virtualbox.xml` and adjusted Default machine folder and machine entry to point to `/home/user/VirtualBox VMs`.
5. `ln -sf /data/common/vbox/Win10Pro ~/VirtualBox VMs/Win10Pro` for each user

## The problem

This only works once... If as user X I open virtualbox and launch the machine, then the permissions on the `/data/common/Win10Pro/*` file(s) revert to rw only for the user after the Virtualbox GUI exits.

*PS:* Earlier I used toe have the disk formatted as exfat and was able to achieve a shared disk/vm using the uid and gid masks but that doesn't work for ext4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for those landing here with a similar predicament, I posted the question on Reddit and was quickly pointed in the right direction

basically:

1. Set the `setgid` bit on the shared folder `/data/common`
2. Set default acl to `rwx` for user and group like so: `setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::r-x /data/common`

A more detailed walkthrough's available here
http://brunogirin.blogspot.com/2010/03/shared-folders-in-ubuntu-with-setgid.html

The article's from 2010 - so the only differences were that I did not have to install any packages or set mount options - ACLs were on by default

Comment: Note, IME this does not work well when you move files in to it. This is partly a regression introduced by `systemd --user` overriding the "umask". Also, if you move photos into such a shared directory from a camera SD card mounted by `udisks`, the same problem occurs even without systemd. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278396/shared-read-write-photo-directory-tree-for-normal-users/430380#430380  Also note, if you have the correct umask set as per https://security.ias.edu/how-and-why-user-private-groups-unix , group writes will be permitted, without needing a default ACL.

Comment: @sourcejedi - Thanks... I'm finding out some of these limitations the hard way. It was way simpler with exfat but it was slow :(. Looks like I can't have my cake and eat it too :(