# umask and Naultilus

Tags: centos, gnome, nautilus, umask

I seem to be having an issue with my applications not obeying the umask. in shell everything seems to be correct, i set my umask to be 002 in a sourced app_env.sh script. this is working correctly as a shell i open will obey this. When i open the file browser and create a new folder, it sets it's permission to be 755.. I also see other applications creating files in this manner, i am unsure of where to set umask so that my applications should follow the rule. I looked around and couldnt find any solutions so far, just unanswered questions on many forums.

Comment: Thank you sebasth for the response. It doesnt seem to have a clear solution in that thread, i added the pam_umask to system_auth, logged out and in and it still seems to be giving the wrong permissions from apps that are launched through gnome. am i missing something?

Comment: I've explained in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379329/239817) the problem why configuring global umask in Gnome 3 sessions does not seem to work.

Comment: Honestly i am upset that there hasn't been much way of a solution to this, i have a studio of artists that use applications to create files and now i need to tell them they cannot create any new files or folders from the gnome session. it seems very backward on GNOME's end. I read all the bug reports, many of them reject this as a bug and ignore any kind of solution or want to fix this issue. Thank you again Sebasth

Comment: @sebasth I may have found a solid workaround [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418224/262925) and i was wondering if you would maybe know how to properly edit the file so that the user isn't actually editing the gdm.service file? any feedback would be appreciated.